# Write mysql command lines

Tags: c++, mysql

I try to implement my own function (without external lib) in C++ which could simply open and exit mysql, with the "system" function.

I tried this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::string command = "mysql -h localhost -u root -proot";
    system(command.c_str());
    const std::string command2 = "exit()";
    system(command2.c_str());

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When i try, the console is connected to mysql console, but the exit command is not passed.
I thought that code could connect and disconnect to mysql service, but it doesn't.

What is wrong? Why doesn't it work ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two calls to `system` have nothing to do with eachother; they are independent and the first one is done before the second one starts.  If you want to pass a string to the first mysql command, maybe something like this would work:

```
const std::string command = "echo 'exit()' | mysql -h localhost -u root -proot";
system(command.c_str());
```

If that does not work you might use `popen`.

Comment: Thx it works !!! And what for several commands ? 
    const std::string command = "echo exit| command3 |command2 | command1 | mysql -h localhost -u root -proot";
    system(command.c_str());

Is this code work ?

Comment: No, but you could do something like `echo "command1\ncommand2\ncommand3" | mysql ...`